# Oracle DBMS - SQL trigger behaving strangely

Tags: sql, oracle

I thought I had the logic right with this trigger, when I insert a new payment into my table, some checks are done against the payment which is inbound vs its due date - it will then set the payment status

```
    /* Handle the users payment status automatically on insert */
-- Has the user paid on time?
IF:NEW.payment_received <= :NEW.payment_due THEN
    :NEW.payment_status := 'PAID';
END IF;
-- Has the user paid late?
IF:NEW.payment_received > :NEW.payment_due THEN
    :NEW.payment_status := 'PAID LATE';
END IF;
-- Is the payment pending?
IF :NEW.payment_due > SYSDATE AND :NEW.payment_received IS NULL THEN
    :NEW.payment_status := 'PENDING';
END IF;
-- Is the payment overdue?
IF :NEW.payment_due < SYSDATE AND :NEW.payment_received IS NULL THEN
    :NEW.payment_status := 'OVERDUE';
END IF;
-- A future payment cannot of been received, set to current date
IF :NEW.payment_received > SYSDATE THEN 
    :NEW.payment_received := SYSDATE;
END IF;
```

The code works for all scenarios apart from `PENDING` and `OVERDUE`.  I just input some dummy data where I set the `:NEW.payment_due` to 28-APR-2014 and `NULL` for for `:NEW.payment_received;`, and the system set its value to `OVERDUE`, this shouldn't be possible given that the date hasn't passed yet, am I missing something here?

Thanks in advance - 
Alex.

Comment: Check your server system date.

Comment: That was my first port of call for debugging this - it returns 04-07-2014 which is correct.

Comment: How do you specify the date value for the new row? If you use a string, then maybe it's an issue with implicit type conversion? Can you show us the complete `INSERT` or `UPDATE` statement?

Comment: Hmm I guess that could be the problem @a_horse_with_no_name, I only specify that it should be a DATE haven't built any input masks yet - however when testing with dummy data I have tried to insert in several formats and the results stay consistent.

Comment: Sorry you lost me. An `update` or `insert` statement does not have "an input mask" nor do you specify a data type when running a DML statement.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, when I say specify a DATE I meant on my table row (but I guess that was self explanatory), I thought you meant how do I handle the format of the DATE string from the client side but I guess I misread what you asked.   

What do you mean by `How do you specify the date value for the new row`

Comment: You can use ISO unseparated date format (YYYYMMDD) literal to specify date to avoid any issues with conversion.

Comment: @HamletHakobyan thank-you I'll look into that, dipping my toes in new water here, I guess there is nothing wrong with my trigger afterall.   Thank-you all.

Comment: "I just input some dummy data" How did you do this? Did you use insert or update statements or did you use Oracle forms?

Comment: @ElectricLlama I ran some `INSERT` statements via SQL Developer

Comment: Post one of your INSERT statements.